# ValueError: Cannot assign "'x'": "y" must be a "z" instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Trying to loop through some order data in a CSV and import it into models I created in Django. Some of the orders are zero'd out with nothing in the field. Attempting to import the data so the customer number defined in the Customer object in models is a ForeignKeyField pulled into the Order object in models.

I get the following error right now:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "'customer_number'": "Order.customer_number" must be a "Customer" instance.

Here is my loop:

```
  for row in reader:
            # print(row)
            print('original date' ,row[4])
            print('total amount', row[26])

            date_string = row[4]

            if not row[26] == '':
                total_amount_decimal = int(float(row[26]))

            else:
                total_amount_decimal = 0

            print("date_string =", date_string)
            print("type of date_string =", type(date_string))

            date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y")

            print("date_object =", date_object)
            print("type of date_object =", type(date_object))

            p, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(customer_number=row[2])
            c, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
                customer_number=row[2], 
                order_number=row[1],
                order_date=date_object,
                total_amount=total_amount_decimal,
            )
```

Here are my models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    

class Order(models.Model):
    customer_number = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8)
```

I tried to search this issue and there seem to be different causes based on the different purposes of the code. I was hoping someone with more experience would be able to quickly identify what I did wrong here. Is there something I can change so the code can loop through the data and pull it into the database without the error?

Comment: You are assigning `'customer_number'` as customer number. Likely because that is the "header" row.

Comment: Use the customer object you created on the previous line: `customer_number=p`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. Don't know why I missed such a glaringly obvious issue with the code but I did.